# Copy/duplicate another linked list

Tags: c#

basically I'm having a slight problem. I just cannot seem to get this to work. I've looked everywhere. I am trying to copy the list using my Concat method

```
public void Concat(LinkListGen<T> list2)
{
    LinkGen<T> temp = list2.list;
    while (temp != null)
    {
        AppendItem(temp.Data);
        temp = temp.Next;
    }
}
```

Which works fine.

However, I'm just not having any luck with my Copy method:

```
public void Copy(LinkListGen<T> list2)
{
    LinkGen<T> temp = list2.list;

    while (temp != null)
    {
        Concat(list2);
        AppendItem(list2.list.Data);
        temp = temp.Next;
    }
}
```

I know this code is probably stupid, I've just been changing the coding/experimenting and trying.

When I execute the code, nothing is displayed.

```
list2.AddItem(56);
list2.AddItem(88);
list2.AddItem(17);

list.AddItem(40);
list.AddItem(11);
list.AddItem(77);

list3.Copy(list2);
list3.Copy(list);

System.Console.WriteLine("Copy List" + list3.DisplayItems());
```

Essentially I want the output like this (may have typed the numbers in the wrong order):

```
Copy List 56 88 17 40 11 77
```

Thank you.

EDIT- I'm an idiot, forgot to the AppendItem method.

```
public void AppendItem(T item)
{
    LinkGen<T> temp = list;
    if (list == null)
    {
        new LinkGen<T>(item, null);
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp.Next != null)
        {
            temp = temp.Next;
        }
        temp.Next = new LinkGen<T>(item, null);
    }
}
```

EDIT --

```
    class LinkGen<T>
{
    private T data;
    private LinkGen<T> next;

    public LinkGen(T item)
    {
        data = item;
        next = null;
    }
    public LinkGen(T item, LinkGen<T> list)
    {
        data = item;
        next = list;
    }
    public LinkGen<T> Next
    {
        set { this.next = value; }
        get { return this.next; }
    }

    public T Data
    {
        set { this.data = value; }
        get { return this.data; }
    }
}
```

}

```
   class LinkListGen<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private LinkGen<T> list;


    public LinkListGen()
    {
        this.list = null;

    }

    public void AddItem(T item)
    {

        list = new LinkGen<T>(item, list);

    }

    public string DisplayItems() //write items to string and return
    {
        LinkGen<T> temp = list;
        string buffer = "";
        while (temp != null) // move one link and add head to the buffer
        {
            buffer += temp.Data + "";
            temp = temp.Next;
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    public int NumberOfItems() // returns number of items in list
    {
        LinkGen<T> temp = list;
        int count = 0;
        while (temp != null) // move one link and add 1 to count
        {
            count++;
            temp = temp.Next;
        }
        return count;
    }



    public void RemoveItem(int item)
    {
        LinkGen<T> current = list;
        LinkGen<T> previous = null;

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.Data.Equals(item))
            {
                if (previous != null)
                {

                    previous.Next = current.Next;
                    current = current.Next;

                }


                else
                {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.Next;
                    list = current;
                }
            }
            else
                previous = current;
            current = previous.Next;
        }

    }



    public void InsertInOrder(T item)
    {
        LinkGen<T> temp = list;

        if (list == null || list.Data.CompareTo(item) < 0)
        {
            list = new LinkGen<T>(item, this.list);
        }
        else
        {
            while (temp != null)
            {

                if (list.Data.CompareTo(item) == 0 || list.Data.CompareTo(item) > 0)
                {
                    temp.Next = new LinkGen<T>(item, temp.Next);

                    temp = null;
                }
                else
                {

                    temp = temp.Next;
                }
            }


        }

    }


    public void AppendItem(T item)
    {
        LinkGen<T> temp = list;
        if (list == null)
        {
            new LinkGen<T>(item, null);
        }
        else
        {
            while (temp.Next != null)
            {
                temp = temp.Next;
            }
            temp.Next = new LinkGen<T>(item, null);
        }
    }


    public void Concat(LinkListGen<T> list2)
    {

        LinkGen<T> temp = list2.list;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            AppendItem(temp.Data);
            temp = temp.Next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing gets printed? are you getting an exception?

Comment: What is `AppendItem`?

Comment: No exception, no errors. Just that line is blank everything before and after is displayed correct, and I've update the topic to show the AppendItem method, basically adds a new item to the end of the list.

Comment: What should copy do? Replace the contents of the current list with the parameter?

Comment: `{ new LinkGen<T>(item, null); }` produces something that is never stored.

Comment: I'm not really sure what is happening in `AppendItem`. What is `list`? What's the point of that ctor not being assigned to anything? Why aren't you using built in copy methods for lists?

Comment: `Copy()` iterates over `temp` but takes data from an unchanging `list2`.

Comment: You may want to print `list2` and `list` before `list3` to make sure they ever get filled. I have my doubts.

Comment: If the idea is `Copy` to replace the content, then the implementation should be `list = null; Concat(list2);`. And to get the desired output, you should use `Copy` followed by `Concat`, e.g.. `list3.Copy(list2); list3.Concat(list);`

Comment: Essentially List 3 is declared and doesn't contain any value, rather it "copies" the exact same values as in both List 1 and List 2. The AppendItem was there for testing purposes, doesn't really mean much in this instance. My bad on that.

Comment: step through your code with a debugger and watch what is happening. Henk points out one major flaw, probably others exist

Answer (score 1):

Suggested correction

```
class LinkListGen<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private LinkGen<T> list;
    public LinkListGen() {  }

    private LinkGen<T> LastNode ()
    {
        var temp = list;
        while (temp != null && temp.Next != null)
            temp = temp.Next;
        return temp;
    } 

    public void AppendItem(T item)
    {
        if (list == null)
            list = new LinkGen<T>(item, null);
        else
        {
            LinkGen<T> temp = LastNode();
            temp.Next = new LinkGen<T>(item, null);
        }
    }

    public void Concat(LinkListGen<T> list2)
    {
        if (list2 == null)
            return;
        LinkGen<T> temp = list2.list;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            AppendItem(temp.Data);
            temp = temp.Next;
        }
    }

    public void Copy(LinkListGen<T> list2)
    {
        Concat(list2);
    }

    class LinkGen<T2>
    {
        public LinkGen(T2 item): this(item, null) { }
        public LinkGen(T2 item, LinkGen<T2> list)
        {
            Data = item;
            Next = list;
        }

        public LinkGen<T2> Next { set;  get; }
        public T2 Data { set ; get ; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I was trying to create a new instance of a LinkGen<T>, kept getting errors are I just entered      LinkGen<T> ThirdList = new LinkGen<T>(list2.list null); or      LinkGen<T> ThirdList = new LinkGen<T>(list2, null);. Thank you for your input kind sir. However, a problem appears on the line     cpTp.Next = new LinkGen<T>(temp.Next, null); The argument stats "Cannot convert from LinkGen<T> to T"

Comment: With all respect, and I truly mean that, it helped to a certian extent. The method is a void type and isn't meant to return a value. Rather it's intended to copy another list which I've already set values for. But I really appreciate the effort. :)

Comment: @ Paul Tsai I'm extremely sorry, but yet again it hasn't worked :(! Darn it. Essentially, Concat will combine two separate LinkedLists into one e.g. List A = [1,2,3] List B = [4,5,6], List C = [1,2,3,4,5,6]. AppendItem will add a new value at the end of the LinkedList e.g. List A [1,2,3] - listA.AppendItem(4); --> List A [1,2,3,4]. And copy is essentially ListA = [1,2,3,4,5]. ListB.Copy(ListA) --- > List B = [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: @ Paul Tsai This is my Concat method which works perfectly fine -     public void Concat(LinkListGen<T> list2)
        {

            LinkGen<T> temp = list2.list;
            while (temp != null)
            {
                AppendItem(temp.Data);
                temp = temp.Next;
            }
        }

Comment: @ Paul Tsai And this is also my AppendItem method which also works without any problems.    public void AppendItem(T item)
        {
            LinkGen<T> temp = list;
            if (list == null)
            {
                new LinkGen<T>(item, null);
            }
            else
            {
                while (temp.Next != null)
                {
                    temp = temp.Next;
                }
                temp.Next = new LinkGen<T>(item, null);
            }
        }

Comment: Sorry for yet again another comment, but these are a few notes I received. // Pre: True
//Post: list contains the same items as in list2
//Hint – easy to write in terms of Concat
I got similar notes for my Concat method                                                  // Pre: True
//Post: list becomes concatenation of list and list2 e.g. [2,3,4], [6,7,8] = [2,3,4,6,7,8]
//Hint – easy to write in terms using AppendItem
So I'm guessing somewhere within the copy method I must use Concat however, I can only seem to get Concat(list2); to work everything else is an error.

Comment: @ Paul Tsai  Sadly, no. I'm not mean to use anything like the private LinkGen<T> LastNode (LinkGen<T> node). I've updated the topic to give you more of an insight into how my code is strucutred. I REALLY, REALLY, appreciate all of this. Thank you.

Comment: @user6353178 Are these methods part of LinkGen or LinkListGen?

Comment: LinkListGen class, the LinkGen class consists of getting setting both the .Data and .Next. I've posted it in my original thread.

Comment: One more clarification. in your example where you have list3.Copy(list2);
list3.Copy(list); Is the expected output actually Copy List 56 88 17 40 11 77? Or should it be 40 11 77 56 88 17?

Comment: Chances are I've posted it in the wrong order. What you're thinking is more than likely correct.

Comment: Sorry about all these questions. I'm still not seeing how concat and copy are any different. Given a ListA and ListB, would the output of ListA.Concat(ListB) be any different from ListA.Copy(ListB)?

Comment: It's fine. And I should've explained it further. List A = [1,2,3] List B = [4,5, 6] I create another instance of a new LinkListGen<T> i.e. List C. I think I most likely confused you by stating ListC.Copy(ListA) & ListC.Copy(ListB). Let's take List B out the equation permanently. So we're left with List A. ListC.Copy(ListA); = List C [ 1,2,3] which is essentially List C == List A ---> ListC.Copy(List C == Whatever list is within this parameter) there's no Concat here. I do apologise. Hope this clears everything up.

Comment: I used both ListA and ListB for testing purposes when writing to the console. My deepest apologise.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not allowed to add another class/change anything of the sort. It's part of my course-work for University haha! Strict guidelines. Alas, I thank you so much for your efforts. It means a lot! Really does! You're a great person! If I could compensate you for your time, I would do so. A thousand thank-you's kind sir.

Comment: If your Concat & Append methods work, simply copy the Copy method and it should work. The code above is logically equivalent.

Comment: this is exactly what I have done. Thank you so much mate!

Answer (score 0):

Answer-

```
  public void Copy(LinkListGen<T> list2)
    {

        LinkGen<T> temp = list2.list;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            AppendItem(temp.Data);
            temp = temp.Next;
        }
    }
```

If anyone ever has the same problem I had. They're finally a solution. Yes, I know.... I'm an idiot!

Comment: Yeah I know. Thank you for your input! :)

Comment: It's just to show the difference. But alas, thank you again. :)